# How To Count Number Of Continuous Blank Cells In Excel and ad to a date

Tags: excel, date, formula

I am trying to recalculate start and end dates.
I have a date in cell `A1`.(Start Date)  Cells `C1` thru `I1` (represent calendar days for a week) have values or blanks. I need to calculate a new start date in `J1` based on the number of consecutive blank cells starting at `C1`.
Then I have a Date in `B1`.(End Date)  I need to calculate new end date in `K1` based on the number of blank consecutive cells from `I1:C1` 
If there is a number in `C1`, report back `A1`.  If there is a number in `I1`, report back `B1`

```
=IFS(C2=" ",A2,A2+1,IF(C2&D2=" ",A2,A2+2))
=IF(C1&D1&E1=" ",A1,A1+3)
```

I've tried count , count blank

If `A1` is 01/01/2019 and the first cell in range `C1:I1` with a number is in `D1` then give me the date of 01/03/2019 in cell `J1`.
AND If `B1` has 01/07/2019 and the first cell with a number from `I1:C1` is `H1` then give me 01/06/2019 in `K1`.
If there is a number in `C1`, report back `A1` (01/01/2019).  If there is a number in `I1`, report back `B1` (01/07/2019)

Answer (score 0):

### How to: Calculate Dates From Columns A & B

*Example Image - Column J*

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,C1:I1<>"",0)+A1-1,"HOLIDAY")`
```

*Example Image - Column K*

```
=IFERROR(A1+(1/(ABS(MIN((-(C1:I1<>""))*COLUMN(C1:I1))))^-1)-3,"HOLIDAY")
```

---

### How to: Lookup Values of First and Last Populated Cells

*Example Image - Column L*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C1:I1,MATCH(TRUE,C1:I1<>"",0)),"HOLIDAY")
```

*Example Image - Column M*

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(C1:I1<>""),C1:I1),"HOLIDAY")
```

[image: Details Matter]

**NOTE - Formulas for Columns J, K, and L are `Array Formulas` and must be entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.  The formula will be enclosed in {curly brackets} if successful.**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=INDEX(C2:I2,1,MATCH(TRUE,C2:I2<>"",0))-2
```

That is a matricial formula so CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER...

Hope it helps

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid formula?

Comment: Already fixed. I am spanish so ";" is my separator, I forgot to change it.